# Django - getting data from url in register view

Tags: python, django, django-views

Im trying to grab data from the url /register/?ref=123456 but having some trouble with it.

User registration is tied to one of my views:

```
class UserRegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    template_name = 'accounts/user_register_form.html'
    success_url = '/accounts/login'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        new_user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
        new_user.set_password(password)
        new_user.save()
        ref = self.request.GET.get('ref', 'None')
        print(ref)
        return super(UserRegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I'm trying to use "self.request.GET.get('ref', 'None')" to grab the data, but each time a user registers ref returns "None" rather than 123456

Here is the user_register_form.html:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-4 offset-sm-4 mt-3'>
        <h1 class='text-center mt-3'>Sign Up</h1>
        <form {% if form_id %} id='{{ form_id }}' {% endif %} class='form mt-3' method='POST' action=''>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input class='btn btn-primary-new' id="submit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You use POST in your template, so why you try to grab it with GET?

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice that. I did switch it to self.request.POST.get('ref', 'None') and ran into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution guys:
I replaced

```
ref = self.request.GET.get('ref', 'None')
```

with

```
ref = (self.request.GET).dict()
data = ref['ref']
```

full implementation:

```
class UserRegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    template_name = 'accounts/user_register_form.html'
    success_url = '/accounts/login'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        new_user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
        new_user.set_password(password)
        new_user.save()
        ref = (self.request.GET).dict()
        data = ref['ref']
        print(data)
        return super(UserRegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```